# jQuery handling element with the same ID

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have element (image button) with same ID... for example:

```
<input type="image" id="butt" src="zzz.jp" />
<input type="image" id="butt" src="zzz.jp" />
<input type="image" id="butt" src="zzz.jp" />
```

and want to understand of which button are clicked by jQuery like:

```
$("#butt").live('click', function(){
    var i ='';
    alert('button '+i+' clicked');
});
```

where variable 'i' needs to be index or number of button which was clicked.

How can I get which button was clicked?

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique. I believe that jQuery stops traversing the DOM once it hits the ID of the element you're looking for, so it will essentially ignore other elements with the same ID that are further down the DOM tree.

Comment: Simply change the IDs to classes: change `id=` to `class=` and give each <input> a unique ID. Then, clicking on an input can trigger the event and you can get teh ID of the <input> element that was clicked.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should use `class` instead of `id`, because **id must be unique**.

Then you can use `jquery.index function` for getting which button is clicked

```
$(".captcha_dwn").live('click', function(){
    var index=$(this).index();
    alert('button '+index+' clicked');
});
```

As of **Jquery v 1.9** [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) has been removed you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead like,

```
$(".captcha_dwn").on('click', function(){
    var index=$(this).index();
    alert('button '+index+' clicked');
});
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/index

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above, here's another way to do what Rohan Kumar suggests:

Here is a [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qmGNF/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.butn').click(function() {
                    var bid = $(this).attr('id');
                    alert(bid);
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <input type="image" class="butn" id="b1" src="zzz.jp" />
    <input type="image" class="butn" id="b2" src="zzz.jp" />
    <input type="image" class="butn" id="b3" src="zzz.jp" />

</body>
</html>
```